# Modeler question: Is there a function in SPSS for multiple 'if' statements? Forecasting dates

Tags: spss-modeler

I am trying to build a forecast for interest expense for floating debt in my company.

I have been given a set of ResetDates which help me match a given rate based on when the ResetDate is.

I have been successful in forecasting one period, but I need a much longer set of periods to satisfy my requirements.

I've tried derive nodes and nested if statements as well as filler nodes.

I am given this data to work with, I can only look at one ResetDate ahead.

[Here you will find the data I used: Columns A/B/C/D is what i'm given, Column E (or 5th column from left to right) is what I want to derive as my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBvw.png)

I want to use 'InterestPayDate' and derive:

if it's more than 'NextReset' , the add 90 days to the 'NextReset' to create 'NextReset2'

That is as far as I can get.... where my problem lies is I want to look at NextReset2 and derive:

if 'InterestPayDate' is more than 'NextReset2', then add 90 days to 'NextReset2', if it's less than 'NextReset2', keep the current value for 'NextReset2'

Output should look like [Column E here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBvw.png)

Not sure if I need to dig deeper into the logical functions, in all honesty, I've just picked up SPSS and I am really trying to learn. Hopefully, you can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As is, it is difficult for users to answer your question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to edit & refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

After computing the first `NextReset2`, you need to use a `Filler` node like the one below to change the value of the field.

[image]

You might need more than one identical nodes like this - one for each potential 90-day period that you are looking to extend the NextReset2 date. In your sample data, you will need at least two `Filler` nodes to get the correct value of `NextReset2` for the last of the records.
There might be a more elegant way to do it, but this will work and it's easy enough to make copies of a node and string them together like this.

Please also see a sample IBM SPSS Modeler stream showing this approach [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZVxcffv0XCKoG-EIvQmnbMPgwz2SMyIu) and using your sample data.

Comment: Kenneth, thank you so much! this is great help. I had done something similar to this but it was duplicating the effort (using the @FIELD was the key)